# File activation error when dynamically creating .mdf database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have tried creating a new database using a class that inherits DataContext.CreateDatabase() and I have also tried a method from a StackExchange post, but both result in the same exception being thrown with a similar traceback.  I have SQL Server 2008 installed, but I have never used it so it's entirely possible I don't have something basic configured.

What I have tried:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
namespace sandbox
{
    public class MyDVDs : DataContext
    {
        public Table<DVD> DVDs;
        public MyDVDs(string connection) : base(connection) { }
    }

    [Table(Name = "DVDTable")]
    public class DVD
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public string Title;
        [Column]
        public string Rating;
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDVDs db = new MyDVDs("mydvds.mdf");
            db.CreateDatabase();
        }
    }
}
```

[Create .mdf/.sdf database dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481890/create-mdf-sdf-database-dynamically)

```
public static void CreateSqlDatabase(string filename)
{
    string databaseName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
    using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
        "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=tempdb; Integrated Security=true;User Instance=True;"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText =
                String.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0} ON PRIMARY (NAME={0}, FILENAME='{1}')", databaseName, filename);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.CommandText =
                String.Format("EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}', 'true'", databaseName);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception and trace:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A file activation error occurred.
>   The physical file name 'testdb.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and
>   correct additional errors, and retry the operation. CREATE DATABASE
>   failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related
>   errors.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>
> at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>
> at sandbox.Program.CreateSqlDatabase(String filename)
>
> at sandbox.Program.Main(String[] args)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the full file path needs to be specified when creating the DataContext object.  Simply using "mydvds.mdf" was not sufficient.

Comment: It also apparently has to be an absolute path, as ".\mydvds.mdf" wasn't working until I changed it to "C:\temp\mydvds.mdf".