# Programmatically creating a database (no permission?)

Tags: c#, sql, database, connection-string

I'm trying to programmatically create a new database (.mdf file) and eventually create tables inside the database. I'm not really sure what connection string to use, I saw the one in the code below thrown around a couple times on multiple sites. I'm getting an error while executing:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

Below is the code that I'm running to create the database:

```
string filename = "C:\\AnalysisResultsDatabase.mdf";
string databaseName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = String.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0} ON PRIMARY (NAME={0}, FILENAME='{1}')", databaseName, filename);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.CommandText = String.Format("EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}', 'true'", databaseName);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your domain account have the necessary permissions to create a database? It looks like you're getting a permission denied error.

Comment: Does [this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10481890/211627) help?

Comment: Any time you use string formatting to build a SQL query, be very mindful of SQL injection. I'm not sure there is an option for CREATE DATABASE, but use parameterized queries for SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128412/sql-injection-is-17-years-old-why-is-it-still-around

Comment: @JDB I had tried that before, that's where most of the code came from. That connection string didn't seem to work at all, simply couldn't even open the connection.

Comment: @CamBruce I don't think it has the necessary permissions, I also can't add a new login because of lack of permissions.

Comment: @KieranPaddock you are going to have to request those permissions from an administrator in order to create databases on the server

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by the SQL Server Instance service identity not having permissions to the location of the MDF file on disk.

Just for checking, try changing the service identity to LocalSystem (if it's not already set to that account).

Answer (score 0):

Your domain account that you are logging into does not have the appropriate permissions for `CREATE DATABASE`. You'll have to contact an administrator who has enough permissions to grant them to you before you can create databases.